# some error in spring mvc registraton program

Tags: spring-mvc, web

I have a problem on this code please help me i have a error like this
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

controllercode:

```
public class RegistrationController  {
@RequestMapping(value="/reg" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String reg(@ModelAttribute("aaa") User user,ModelMap model,BindingResult res){
    model.addAttribute("Fname",user.getFname());
    System.out.println(user.getFname());
    model.addAttribute("Lname", user.getLname());
    model.addAttribute("Email", user.getEmail());
    model.addAttribute("Pwd", user.getPwd());
    model.addAttribute("Phnum", user.getPhnum());
    return "NewFile";


  }
}

<form:form method="POST" action="/reg" name="aaa">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="127"><form:label path="Fname">Employee Id:</form:label></td>
                <td width="102"><form:input path="Fname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="127"><form:label path="Lname">Employee Id:</form:label></td>
                <td width="102"><form:input path="Lname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="127"><form:label path="Email">Employee Id:</form:label></td>
                <td width="102"><form:input path="Email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="127"><form:label path="Pwd">Employee Id:</form:label></td>
                <td width="102"><form:input path="Pwd" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="127"><form:label path="Phnum">Employee Id:</form:label></td>
                <td width="102"><form:input path="Phnum" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/reg" name="aaa">
```

to

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/reg" commandName="aaa">
```

or

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/reg" modelAttribute="aaa">
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your valuable suggestion i changed that to modelattribute but now also its showing this error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/registration.jsp at line 15

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'aaa' available as request attribute

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/registration.jsp at line 15
```

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/registration.jsp at line 15

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/registration.jsp at line 15

```
12:   <form:form method="POST" action="/reg" modelAttribute="aaa">
13:             <table>
14:                 <tr>
15:                     <td width="127"><form:label path="Fname">Employee Id:</form:label></td>
16:                     <td width="102"><form:input path="Fname" /></td>
17:                 </tr>
18:                 <tr>
```